# angularjs-google-maps - info-window does not work with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angularjs-google-maps

I use google maps with ng-map and use markers and info-windows attached to these markers added to the map with ng-repeat. My angular view is the following:

```
<div id="mapWrap" map-lazy-load="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js">      
<map center="current-location" zoom="9" on-bounds_changed="getLocations()">

    <marker  ng-repeat="myMarker in myMarkers"
        clickable="true"
        on-click="showInfoWindow(event, '{{myMarker.infoWindowId}}')"
        id="{{myMarker.id}}"
        position="[{{myMarker.lat}},{{myMarker.lon}}]"
        title="{{myMarker.title}}"
        draggable="false"
        opacity="{{myMarker.opacity}}"
        visible="{{myMarker.visible}}"
        icon="{{myMarker.icon}}">
    </marker>

    <info-window ng-repeat="infoWindow in infoWindows" 
        id="{{infoWindow.id}}" 
        visible-on-marker="{{infoWindow.markerId}}">
            <div ng-non-bindable="">
                <h1>{{infoWindow.name}}</h1>
                <p>{{infoWindow.text}}</p>
                <a href="{{infoWindow.url}}">Get forecast</a>
            </div> 
    </info-window>

</map>
</div>
```

the `myMarker.infoWindowId` correspond to `infoWindow.id` and `myMarker.id` to `infoWindow.markerId`. There seems to be no issue in that, the markers and the infowindows are listed just fine in the DOM after loading the view and controller.

The markers are shown just fine on the map, as they are updated when the `on-bounds_changed="getLocations()"` function is executed.

The list of info-windows is updated in `getLocations()` too, the markers and the info-windows can be seen in the DOM, but the info-windows are not shown when I click on the corresponding marker. Tried using a single info-window item in the view and update its content when the user clicks on a marker, but nothing changed.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction to what am I not doing right here? Thank you.

A second question: if I must use `ng-non-bindable` in the info-window content (ng-map complains otherwise), how can I dynamically update/generate the content of the info-window? But this issue should show up only after the infow-windows are shown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry for the late response.

short answer, `info-window` must not be used with `ng-repeat`.

http://plnkr.co/edit/lBxdmm?p=preview

```
  <marker  ng-repeat="myMarker in myMarkers"
      name="A" text="B" url="http://foo.bar"
      clickable="true"
      on-click="showInfoWindow('myInfoWindow')"
      id="{{myMarker.id}}"
      position="[{{myMarker.lat}},{{myMarker.lng}}]"
      draggable="false"
      opacity="{{myMarker.opacity}}">
  </marker>

  <info-window id="myInfoWindow">
    <div ng-non-bindable="">
        <h1>{{this.name}}</h1>
        <p>{{this.text}}</p>
        <a href="{{this.url}}">Get forecast</a>
    </div> 
  </info-window>
```